# Puma: "Same File" error when testing filename edit using FileUtils.mv()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails, fileutils

I'm writing unit tests for my Rails 5 app using Rspec and Capybara, and I'm currently stuck trying to test the ability to rename files uploaded to my controller. The app seems to work flawlessly: I have a Documents controller with an attached File thanks to Paperclip, and a view that allows the user to edit the filename (without the extension), so when the user clicks on the Save button, the controller uses FileUtils to "rename" the file:

```
@document = Document.find(params[:id])
path = @document.file.path
@document.file_file_name = params[:document][:filename] + '.' + params[:document][:extension]
@document.project_id = params[:document][:project_id]
@document.user_id = params[:document][:user_id]
FileUtils.mv(path, File.join(File.dirname(path), @document.file_file_name))
```

this has been thoroughly tested by several teammates and it doesn't break so far. However, the problem comes when trying to run my unit test:

```
RSpec.describe "documents/edit.html.erb", type: :feature do

# Creating user, document, and related models...

  it "edits a file as Admin" do
    sign_in @user_admin
    visit edit_document_path(@document)
    find('#document_filename').set('edited_filename')
    find("input[type=submit][value='Save']").click
    expect(page).to have_content("edited_filename.docx")
  end
end
```

And then, when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Failures:

1) documents/edit.html.erb edits a file as Admin
   Failure/Error: FileUtils.mv(path, File.join(File.dirname(path), @document.file_file_name))

 ArgumentError:
   same file: /home/moyarzun/GarageLabs/lexgo/public/system/documents/files/000/000/001/original/test_file.docx and /home/moyarzun/GarageLabs/lexgo/public/system/documents/files/000/000/001/original/edited_filename.docx
```

This is not a Rails error, but a Puma one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dAxT.png

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing  `/home/moyarzun/GarageLabs/lexgo/public/system/documents/files/000/000/001/original/test_file.docx` is actually a soft link to a file elsewhere in the system, and that a link to the same file named `/home/moyarzun/GarageLabs/lexgo/public/system/documents/files/000/000/001/original/edited_filename.docx` already exists when you're running the test (because the tests aren't clearing out the links created each time it's run).  If you try and move a link to another another link which is already linked to the same file you'll get the 'same file` argument error.  You want to make sure you clean up files from tests when the tests complete (or before running the tests).

Comment: TIL that files uploaded during tests are stored on the same production file system, and that edited files using the FileUtils.mv function keep both the original and the target file during tests. So what I ended up doing was deleting the file after each test  using the target path:

  after do
    FileUtils.rm("#{Rails.root}/public/system/documents/files/000/000/001/original/edited_filename.docx")
  end